# darknet doesn't use p5000 gpu with cuda

Tags: artificial-intelligence, object-detection, opencv3.0, darknet

i run this command

```
./darknet detector train data/obj.data  cfg/yolov3_training.cfg back/last_4_4_7pm.weights /back -dont_show -gpus 0
```

but gou is not been used and 0 %

here is my makefile;:

```
%cd darknet
!sed -i 's/OPENCV=0/OPENCV=1/' Makefile
!sed -i 's/GPU=0/GPU=1/' Makefile
!sed -i 's/CUDNN=0/CUDNN=1/' Makefile
```

here is the out put

```
CUDA-version: 11020 (11000)
 Warning: CUDA-version is higher than Driver-version! 
, cuDNN: 8.1.0, GPU count: 1  
 OpenCV version: 3.4.11
0
yolov3_training
 0 : compute_capability = 610, cudnn_half = 0, GPU: Quadro P5000 
net.optimized_memory = 0 
mini_batch = 4, batch = 64, time_steps = 1, train = 1 
   layer   filters  size/strd(dil)      input                output
   0 Create CUDA-stream - 0 
 Create cudnn-handle 0
```

here is my nvidia smi:

```
root@n5qr6jidhm:/notebooks/Untitled Folder/darknet# nvidia-smi
```

Fri Jun 25 17:53:45 2021
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.36.06    Driver Version: 450.36.06    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro P5000        On   | 00000000:00:05.0 Off |                  Off |
| 39%   62C    P0   126W / 180W |   5725MiB / 16278MiB |     92%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

Answer (score 0):

First, start with upgrading(downgrading) your drives by gpu model. That can be easily found on google. Then check driver versions with darknet min. req. before installing them. Don't use -gpus flag as nothing changes.